# Magento2 SOAP with C#

Tags: magento2, soap, webapi, c#

I am trying to read Magento customer from a C# third-party software.
When I enter SOAP into the browser, its throwing error.

URL:-
    http://localhost:81/magento2-2.2.5/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerMetadataV1

Error:-
    Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Please suggesr how to resolve this error.

Thanks
Gautam